# jQuery: How to hide an element and then reveal another?

Tags: jquery, css

I am pretty new with jQuery and I am trying to achieve a simple interaction.

**Scenario**
I have a circle and a square on my page. The square is hidden (display:none) by default. When I hover my mouse on the circle, it will reveal a link in it. When you click on it, the circle will fade away and the square will fade in.

**Problem**
The circle fades away and the square fades in but the square gets hidden after it fades in. The display:block property doesn't seem to work?

**Code**
http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/urFid

I have edited the code, it works now.

```
$(function(){
  $("#click").on("click", function(){
    $(".circle").addClass("fade-out");
    $(".square").addClass("fade-in");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It seems like a simple task but it is mind boggling for many people. Anyway I have figured it out. In your @keyframe fade-in, just add 0% { opacity: 0 } and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I just figured out.
The problem is in the @keyframe fade-in.

http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/urFid

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code works but **`opacity`** of square is still `0` even after it is displayed.

**2options:**
1) remove opacity in **`square`**

```
.square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

2) or add opacity in **`fade-in`**

```
.fade-in{
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade-in .5s  ease-in-out 1; 
}
```

Comment: 1) Remove opacity in square will not get the fade in effect I want. Green will just suddenly show. Animation needs to start from somewhere, in this case 0 --> 1. 

2) opacity: 1 will not work, it will just get applied to the square immediately. No fade in effect

Comment: Yeap, I was the one who did the code. Thanks to your comment "Actually your code works but opacity of square is still 0 even after it is displayed." I was like ohhh! of course! So I figured that out (: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `opacity 0` from `.square`

Comment: I need the opacity. The animation has to start from opacity 0 to 1 to achieve the fadeIn effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sU93j/)

**CSS**

```
fade-out{

  display:none;  
  animation: fade-out .5s  ease-in-out 1; 
}

.fade-in{
  display: block;
  opacity:1;
  animation: fade-in .5s  ease-in-out 1; 
}
```

Comment: there is no "fade in" effect. when the element gets apply .fade-in, it gets opacity 1 straight away.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#click").on("click",function(){
    $(".circle").fadeOut(200,function(){
    $(".square").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/dSR9s/

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking at only using CSS for visual effects. Not relying on jQuery on fading elements.

Comment: Thanks yMed, but maybe try taking a look at my new updated code. http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/urFid I am thinking it is alot more elegant. (: